# There are 2 quotation marks before and after the json fields (bug spark?)

Tags: java, json, spark-csv

I have an object

```
class JsonOutput {

    @JsonProperty("blah")
    private String blah;

    @JsonProperty("blah_blah")
    private String blahBlah;

    @JsonProperty("int_val")
    private String intVal;

    JsonOutput(String b, String bb, Integer i) {
       this.blah = b;
       this.blahBlah = bb;
       this.intVal = i;
    }

    // getters
}
```

that I use for creating a json in a string (with jackson):

```
JsonOutput jsonOutput = new JsonOutput("text1", "text2", 20);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInfo = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonOutput);
```

jsonInfo seems ok: `{"blah":"text1","blah_blah":"text2","int_val":20}` but when writing it to csv with spark I get double quotation for each string:

```
"{""blah"":""text1"",""blah_blah"":""text2"",""int_val"":20}"
```

It seems like it is doing the escaping by `"`.

I have tried to change the `option("escape", "\\")` but the output has not change. If I change the `option("quote", "\\")`, then the output changes:

```
\{"blah":"text1","blah_blah":"text2","int_val":20}\
```

This seems to me like a bug in the spark library: it is doing the escaping with quote. Did anyone meet this problem?

Comment: There's only one string.

Comment: no, for the Integer fields I get `""int_field"":354`

Comment: How are you viewing this string?

Comment: Actually it is a part of an app that is using spark and it is in a dataframe at the end, saved in a csv

Comment: Oops, you are right, if I do System.out.println(jsonInfo) it is ok... sorry

I'll update the question if I find the problem

Comment: CSV doubles up quotes within content, so perhaps this is due to something in Spark doing it? Jackson does not do such doubling up for JSON, ever.

Comment: Yes it is, I thin it's in the saving part... sorry. Should I delete the question?